# Is there a way to map the NUMBER field in Oracle to multiple numeric fields in SQL Server in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, ssis

I'm trying to move data from Oracle to SQL Server.  We have a large number of NUMBER fields in the original Oracle 11g schema.  In SSIS, we are using an OLE destination control.  Most of the NUMBER fields are mapping to float fields.

We are using the attunity connectors.  I understand that there are mapping xml files in SSIS that will map numeric data types to SSIS data types; however, I need something that will take a sample of the data and infer the correct numeric, sql server destination data type.

Is there a solution for this problem?  There are a lot of fields, we are worried about manually mapping them.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a very dangerous approach. Don't infer data type from the data itself. If anything, look at the column definition and constraints on the column. Otherwise you may be better off leaving them all as FLOAT.

Comment: I've heard however that floats lose data because they are approximations.

Comment: So are decimals (the Oracle NUMBER data type); 1/3 cannot be represented exactly either in binary or in decimal. The only difference is that decimal can represent 1/5 exactly (and therefore 1/10 as well), while binary (i.e. float) can't. Do you really care about losing the 14th decimal place? Then: this will affect fractional numbers only; integers are represented with 100% accuracy in FLOAT and in NUMBER, unless you have very large numbers. Do you? If the numbers aren't too large and you are really concerned about accuracy, you can use DECIMAL.